# How to configure multiple solace queues in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, solace

I am trying to configure multiple SOLACE queues in my spring boot application using below code:

```
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {

@Bean(name="queue1")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue1"
public ConnectionFactory queue1ConnectionFactory() {
    return new PoolingConnectionFactoryBean();
}

@Bean(name="queue2")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue2")
public ConnectionFactory queue2ConnectionFactory() {
    return new PoolingConnectionFactoryBean();
}
```

}

Below is the way I am trying to give properties:

```
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue1.class-name=com.solacesystems.jms.SolXAConnectionFactoryImpl
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue1.driverProperties.host=<<hostURL1>>
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue1.driverProperties.VPN=<<VPN1>>
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue1.driverProperties.authentication-scheme=AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_GSS_KRB
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue1.driverProperties.KRBServiceName=HOST


spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue2.class-name=com.solacesystems.jms.SolXAConnectionFactoryImpl
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue2.driverProperties.host=<<hostURL2>>
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue2.driverProperties.VPN=<<VPN2>>
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue2.driverProperties.authentication-scheme=AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_GSS_KRB
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.queue2.driverProperties.KRBServiceName=HOST
```

The maven build is getting successful but I am facing issues while deploying the code on apaas cloud. Below exception is faced:

> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
>   start embedded Tomcat     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>     at
>   com.barclays.magics.slam.MagSlamApplication.main(MagSlamApplication.java:25)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
>     ... 16 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]:
>   Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint'
>   parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]:
>   Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13434908]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with  name 'queue1ConnectionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [JmsConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JMS
>   connection factory named queue1ConnectionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:235)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5098)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:372)    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106)
>     ... 21 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]:
>   Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint'
>   parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]:
>   Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13434908]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'queue1ConnectionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [JmsConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JMS
>   connection factory named queue1ConnectionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
>     ... 61 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint'
>   parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]:
>   Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13434908]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'queue1ConnectionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [JmsConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JMS
>   connection factory named queue1ConnectionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e38d5663.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0()
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e38d5663$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4f06b7b.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e38d5663.servletEndpointRegistrar()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>     ... 62 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]:
>   Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13434908]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'queue1ConnectionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [JmsConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested

Any pointers will be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to send to multiple queues on the same broker you don't need to specify multiple connection factories. Solace supports Spring Autoconfig for JMS so you can autowire a *JmsTemplate* and then use the *convertAndSend* method to send a message to different queues.

The example here shows sending to one queue but each time you call *convertAndSend* you can use a different string as the queue name.
https://github.com/Mrc0113/solace-samples-spring/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfig-sender/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/spring/boot/SpringBootSender.java

Note that this code is not creating the queue so it must already exist on the broker.